# How do you remove data from the ember store that has been loaded?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

As I click on items on my ember app the server is called and the data is loaded in the model store.

My question is how can I remove that data that is loaded in for that specific model to be removed, so that when I click on that item again it would call out to the server again and pull the data back.

I have seen some previous answers that running something like, `App.store.findQuery(App.Model, {})`, would invalidate the cache, but that does not seem to work.

Is there a way to iterate over just the items that have been loaded into the store and call `.reload()` on them? or a way to just clear it all out?

Any ideas or help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want to do is unload all of the cached models for a particular type?

```
//From a route or controller...
this.store.unloadAll('post');
```

Comment: FYI, there is currently a bug with the unloadAll implementation. There is a PR https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1482 to fix the issue.